# grep and curl commands

Tags: linux, url, curl, terminal, grep

I am trying to find the instances of the word (pattern) "Zardoz" in the output of this command:

```
curl http://imdb.com/title/tt0070948
```

I tried using: `curl http://imdb.com/title/tt0070948 | grep "Zardoz"`

but it just returned "file not found".

Any suggestions? I would like to use grep to do this.

Comment: Set a useragent to simulate a browser

Comment: Actually, imdb on tihs reques returns a 301 redirection, which curl only follows if you give the `-L` option

Comment: where do you see the "301"? Or rather, how do you identify a 301 redirection?

Comment: @Edson: You can check it with `curl --head` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell curl use to `-L` (--location) option:

```
curl -L http://imdb.com/title/tt0070948 | grep "Zardoz"
```

> (HTTP/HTTPS) If the server reports that the requested  page  has
>                 moved to a different location (indicated with a Location: header
>                 and a 3XX response code), this option will make  curl  redo  the
>                 request on the new place
>
> When  curl follows a redirect and the request is not a plain GET
>                 (for example POST or PUT), it will do the following request with
>                 a GET if the HTTP response was 301, 302, or 303. If the response
>                 code was any other 3xx code, curl  will  re-send  the  following
>                 request using the same unmodified method

.